# Why does my java code not compile

Tags: java

The file compiles and works as expected but when I try to use it in another file it keeps saying when I attempt to compile. So clearly I don't know how to import code from another file correctly. How do I import the file  for use within , I have read many explanations but they all require an IDE which I don't plan on using, I am using notepad++.

Comment: its the `import` statement on `Centralize` class, its looking for package.

Comment: Do you compile both files together or separately? Also, I don't see any package declaration in your ReadFile.java while you seem to expect one in Centralise (import ReadFile.*;).

Comment: What should I write on the import to be able to use ReadFile then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do `import ReadFile.*;` but `ReadFile` is not the package name but the class name. 
Package allows you to categorize your classes. Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package for more details.

Put your `ReadFile.java` into a package (for example: `package org.your-company.io`) then in the second class:

```
import org.your-company.io.ReadFile;
```

The instruction `import somepackage.*` indicates that you can use any classes from the package `somepackage` in your current class.
For example, if I do:

```
import java.sql.*;
```

I will be able to call, in my code, directly:

```
Date dsql = ... // java.sql.Date
DriverManager driver = ... // java.sql.DriverManager
etc.
```

**Edit**

As Dukeling mentionned in a comment, if your classes are in the same "folder" (I mean **package**), you can remove your instruction `import ReadFile.*` which is wrong and useless.

Comment: Good answer, but you should elaborate. What should he do? Why is that not working?

Comment: ... or if it's in the same package (which could be no package - which appears to currently be the case), there's no need to import it.

Comment: What is a package? I just have a folder with three files: ReadFile.java, ReadFile.class and Centralise.java. How would I use ReadFile within Centralise?

Comment: So a package is just a folder. If your files are in the same folder, you don't need any imports.

Comment: @user3701257 : You can take a look on Oracle tutorial which will explain you the package concept: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/

Comment: Dukeling is right, you can simply remove your `import ReadFile.*` instruction and it should work.

Comment: Ok. I got rid of the import but I now get a new error: `Error: cannot find symbol` while pointing towards the line `ArrayList<String> lines = ReadFile.openFile("text.txt");` more specifically pointing towards `ReadFile`. What do I do here?

Comment: you have to declare package name in all your classes (at the first line). For example, if you're in `org/your-company/io` folder, you will write `package org.your-company.io;`. I hope you understand what I mean. The best thing is to follow a tutorial.

Comment: @user3701257 That probably means Notepad++ is just trying to compile your file without considering other files in the same directory - you should perhaps read a (perhaps Notepad++ or perhaps generic) tutorial on compiling multiple Java files. Also, `openFile` isn't `static`, so you need an object to call it (you can't just say `ReadFile.openFile`) (or make it `static`), but that won't cause the error you're getting.

Comment: Notepad++ is just a text editor, I am not compiling with it. I am using the command prompt in order to compile using the command `javac ReadFile.java` and `javac Centralise.java`.

Comment: I put everything within the folder Centralise then added the line `package Centralise;` to the top of each java file and it still gives me the same error @lpratlong

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling well? You can take info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511083/compiling-multiple-classes-console-in-java

Comment: Ohh right I was compiling separately, thanks.